# Plot with colored data points

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot, r-plotly

Does anyone know how I can specify in the legend of my plot the colored data points?

```
with(data, plot(Math,FamilySize, pch=21, bg = StudyTime, cex=0.8))
legend('topright', pch = 19, legend = c(1,2,3,4),  cex = 1, col = data$StudyTime)
```

The values in the category are from 1-4 and the data points should be in four different colors. However, I am getting an incorrect legend because it does not equal to the colors in my points.

Comment: simply try `col =1:4` in the legend function

Comment: Miloud, it would help considerably if you either (a) used a dataset that we all have (e.g., `iris`, `mtcars`); or (b) provide a sample of your data in a way that we can easily use, such as `dput(head(data,n=10))`. Otherwise it's a little difficult to infer everything you need.